# How to get session information in Spring MVC 3

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC and I am trying to get the session information in my controller class

Right now I am using

> HttpSession objHttpSession = request.getSession(true);

if I want to get session creation time and session Id I am using

> objHttpSession.getCreationTime();
>   objHttpSession.getId();

I want to know is there any spring MVC specific way to get the session details?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 45):

I usually declare a parameter of type HttpSession in my Spring MVC controller method when I need to access session details.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping("/myrequest")
public void handleMyRequest(HttpSession session, ...) {
   ...
}
```

I think it's the simplest way, but don't know if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 26):

You can get the session in Spring MVC like this:

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();
```

The `currentRequestAttributes` method return the `RequestAttributes` currently bound to the thread in which there is a current request and from that request you can get the session. This is useful when you need to get hold of the session in non-spring class. Otherwise you can just use:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public void myMethod(HttpSession session) {   
}
```

Spring will inject `HttpSession` instance into your controller's method.

Comment: This answer is also correct, however it introduces extra information not requested by OP.  The OP specifically requests a "Spring MVC" way to get the session.